Cloudstack and VMware vCenter integration
I am currently building a multi hypervisor setup of cloudstack.
Currently I am using KVM hypervisors, but I am in the process of connecting a VMware vcenter 8.x to my cloudstack evironment.
I want to use distributed switches as the enviroment has the potential to grow very large. But all the documentation i find for connecting the vcenter and enabling distributed virtual switches is essentially obsolete. Referencing settings and options that are no longer available in the cloudstack UI. And the integration process is difficult to follow as significant changes have happened since vsphere 6.5...
What I am trying to get to the bottom of, is the mapping made of the distributed switches and the representation in the cloudstack UI.
Essentially what variables are being matched with the name of the distributed vSwitch in the vcenter In order to manage it?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Its alright guys, I fixed it.
In the cloudstack UI.
Under Zones -> "ZoneName" -> Physical network -> under the physical network (eg. management) there is a button named "Update Traffic labels"
There you open a dialougebox where there is a field named "VMWare traffic label" The value you put in this field Cloudstack tries to match against the name of a vswitch on your esxi-host.
If you leave this field empty, it will default look for vSwitch0 which is the default vSwitch in an VMware esxi installation.
